# SPDT switch with MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, switches, cmos

I'm trying to create an analog signal switch in logic CMOS to achieve an SPDT switch, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome! Have you looked commercial offerings? Re-inventing the wheel is often a less favorable alternative.

Comment: Yes, and I found this DS2413 component, but it uses SPI communication and I'd prefer to control everything by simply raising or lowering 1/2 digital pins. Additionally, I would like to try to understand how to implement it using MOSFETs .

Comment: @dc_ [MAX20337](https://www.analog.com/en/products/max20337.html) is an example of a SPDT analog switch controlled by a single digital input. What voltage and current do you need the analog SPDT switch to operate with?

Comment: The voltages at play are quite small (at most a few hundred millivolts) coming from a DAC. I need the switch to move the DAC from one part of the circuit to another. Do you have any guidance on how to do it with MOSFETs? I'm really curious...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.